# Read object properties with node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

My **node.js** server receives data from a form with an **ajax** post request. Form enctype is `"multipart/form-data"`. I send three strings and one image and the best way I've found to access these data is by using the `"multiparty"` module.
This is the situation

```
dispatcher.addListener("post", "/admin/req", function(req, res) {
  // parse a file upload
var form = new multiparty.Form({uploadDir: __dirname + "/tmp"});

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

  console.log(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
  console.log(files['img_event']);
  });
 });
```

and this is the outpout

```
//first log
     { fields: 
       { name_event: [ 'blablabla' ],
         data_event: [ 'blabla' ],
        },
      files: { img_event: [ [Object] ] } }

//second log
    [ { fieldName: 'img_event',
        originalFilename: 'screenshot 2014-10-11 16:57:54.png',
        path: '/home/myusername/Desktop/nodeapp/tmp/15620-v12gsy.png',
        headers: 
         { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="img_evento"; filename="Schermata del 2014-10-11 16:57:54.png"',
           'content-type': 'image/png' },
        ws: 
         { _writableState: [Object],
           writable: true,
           domain: null,
           _events: [Object],
           _maxListeners: 10,
           path:  '/home/myusername/Desktop/nodeapp/tmp/15620-v12gsy.png',
           fd: null,
           flags: 'w',
           mode: 438,
           start: undefined,
           pos: undefined,
           bytesWritten: 149910,
           closed: true },
        size: 149910 }
```

now, if i try to access the property "path" or any other by:

```
  console.log(files['img_event'].path);
  or
  console.log(files['img_event']['path'];
```

it always returns `"undefined"`.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Because, `files['img_event']` is an Array, not an Object. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(files['img_event']));
// [object Array]
```

So, you need to access the first element in the array, like this

```
files['img_event'][0].path
```